# Не понимаю процесс(как организовать) защищённый API при помощи lcobucci/jwt?

Tags: php, jwt

В мануалах про `jwt` пишут, что аутентификацию пользователя можно реализовать даже без хранения токена в бд. Какой в таком случае алгоритм действий? Так как у меня в голове только один алгоритм: пользователь отправляет например `post` запрос в формате `json` по определённому `url`. И методом сравнения в бд понимаю, давать доступ или нет. Но это не тру. Правильно сделать, чтобы он обращался без пароля и логина только по хеш ключу. Как раз для этого и придумали `jwt`. Я скачал пакет `lcobucci/jwt`. И с генерировал ключ. А дальше что? Что пользователь должен мне передать чтобы формировать ему его отдельный ключ? И потом пускать его по нему? И чтобы это было безопасно.

Comment: Весь смысл jwt, в том что он хранит в себе всю необходимую информацию. Сразу предупреждаю вас, что jwt токен нельзя отозвать. Т.е. он будет работать пока не протухнет.

Comment: @ArchDemon Мне надо выгружать по одному и тому же `url` для каждого пользователя свою информацию. Как мне понять кому дать доступ и соответственно токен, а кому не дать?

Comment: @ArchDemon А также мне ещё необходимо эти данные принимать.

Comment: Если у юзера нет токена, вы всё проверяете валидность юзера и выдаёте ему токен. В дальнейшем, если к вам приходит токен, то вы не лезете в базу и не проверяете валидность юзера. Наличие токена уже говорит о валидности.

Comment: @ArchDemon Ок. Я так понимаю, что каждому юзеру я даю свой уникальный `jwt`. Тогда мне не понятно как понимать что это верные ключи?

Comment: Каждый ключ шифруется сервером. Если сервер смог расшифровать токен, то он его и зашифровал.

Comment: @ArchDemon то, есть проверка будет такова: я получаю `jwt` - декодирую 2 часть токена (например там id пользователя), полученные данные кодирую снова с использованием секретного ключа и если подписи равны - пускаю. Так? И подскажите пожалуйста, какой `header();` мне отправлять? Так как этот токен должен быть в заголовке.

Comment: Нет. Вы получаете от пользователя логин и пароль (в самом простом варианте). Проверяете пару на валидность. В случае успеха выдаёте пользователю токен со всей нужной информацией. А уж где токен передавать - это определяет ваш код. Хотите в заголовке, хотите в post или get данных